# Since java performs both compilation and interpretation for the source code does that mean javac compiles the code and java interprets\runs code

Tags: java

I wrote this code in file named Hello.java

```
public class Hello{
    System.out.println("Hello there");
}
```

then I wrote command `javac hello.java`
and `java hello`
and prints successfully

However if I make changes to the code and write

```
public class Demo{
     System.out.println("New hello");
}
```

and run command `java hello.java`
This also works and prints successfully. However I am not following any Java parameters(file name and class name should be same) for defining class name so why does this works?

I know I am doing the wrong way but if I didn't follow the pattern it shouldn't execute, right ?!
and if I knowingly make semicolon mistake and run the command `java hello.java` it says compilation failed, but isn't the task of compilation complete ?

Comment: You now have two class files. You invoke the old one.

Comment: Even if I make changes and don't compile at the first place and just run the file with .java extension it still runs but why, that's the question here

Comment: New versions of the java command  can invoke javac under the covers.

Comment: Starting with Java 11, the `java` command is able to compile and run a Java source file in one step.  Why?  Because they changed it so that you can do that.  What is going on?  Read the manual ... carefully.

Comment: I didn't know the source-file mode compiled into memory.  It sounds like Oracle would like to be able to write small scripts in Java.

Comment: and my first comment was wrong.  Misread the question

Answer (score 2):

What you've encountered here is a "source-file" mode of java launcher:
Java launcher has 4 launching modes:

- launching a class file
- launching the main class of a JAR file
- launching the main class of a module.
- launching a class declared in a source file.

We are talking about fourth option here:

> In source-file mode, the effect is as if the source file is compiled into memory, and the first class found in the source file is executed. For example, if a file called HelloWorld.java contains a class called hello.World, then the command
> *java HelloWorld.java*
> is informally equivalent to
> *javac -d <memory> HelloWorld.java*
> *java -cp <memory> hello.World*

> The compiler does not enforce the optional restriction defined at the end of JLS §7.6, that a type in a named package should exist in a file whose name is composed from the type name followed by the .java extension.

For more info read the [specification Jep 330](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330).